# What is a primitive character of a Galois groups of a finite cyclic extension of local fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, definition, characters

Let $K$ be a local field and $F/K$ be a cyclic extension of degree $n$, meaning that $n = [F:K]$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(F/K) \simeq C_n$ is cyclic.

In the proof of Lemma 2 of the paper ["Euler Factors determine local Weil Representation" by Tim and Vladimir Dokchitser](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4889.pdf) we considered a **primitve character** $\chi$ of $\operatorname{Gal}(F/K)$.

**Question**: What exactly is a **primitive character**? (Unfortunately, I was not able to find a proper definition somewhere.)

- Does it has something to do with the Galois group being cyclic? Or is there a more general definition?
- Do we need a Weil representation here (as this paper deals with them)?
- Are these related with Dirichlet characters? (My professor mentioned them once but I still have no idea what they are.)

It would be really nice if you could respond to my questions. Thank you!

Comment: This is only what I know as primitive character. Consider an finite abelian extension $K/Q$. Then it follows from Kronecker $K\subset Q[m]$ where $Q[m]$ is $m-$th cyclotomic extension. Denote $G_m=Gal(Q[m]/Q)$. Then $G_m\to Gal(K/Q)$ surjection induces $\hat{Gal(K/Q)}\to \hat{G_m}$ embedding by dual. Now $m$ is taken minimal for a character $\chi\in\hat{Gal(K/Q)}$ and denote that image in corresponding $\hat{G_m}$ as primitive character.(i.e. It cannot come from character of smaller cyclotomic extension.) For this case, they are certainly dirichlet characters by kronecker-webber.

Comment: @user45765 And there is the corresponding (Dirichlet or Hecke) character on the $O_K$ side obtained from the [Artin map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_reciprocity_law), which is essentially a character of $(O_K/\mathfrak{a})^\times$ (for some ideal $\mathfrak{a}$) or a character of a class group